# Is there a way to make threads run slow?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue

This question is probably opposite of what every developer wants their system to do.

I am creating a software that looks into a directory for specific files and reads them in and does certain things. This can create high CPU load. I use `GCD` to make threads which are put into `NSOperationQueue`. What I was wondering, is it possible to make this operation not take this huge CPU load? I want to run things way slower, as speed is not an issue, but that the app should play very nice in the background is very important.

In short. Can I make `NSOperationQueue` or threads in general run slowly without using things like sleep?

The app traverses a directory structure, finds all images and creates thumbnails. Just the traversing of the directories makes the CPU load quite high.

Comment: Have you looked at the `priority` parameter to the `dispatch_get_global_queue` function?

Answer (score 0):

Process priority: nice / renice.

See:
https://superuser.com/questions/42817/is-there-any-way-to-set-the-priority-of-a-process-in-mac-os-x#42819
but you can also do it programmatically.

Your threads are being CPU-intensive. This leads to two questions:

1. Do they need to be so CPU-intensive? What are they doing that's CPU-intensive? Profile the code. Are you using (say) a quadratic algorithm when you could be using a linear one?
2. Playing nicely with other processes on the box. If there's nothing else on the box then you /want/ to use all of the available CPU resource: otherwise you're just wasting time. However, it there are other things running then you want to defer to them (within reason), which means giving your process a lower priority (i.e. /higher/ nice value) than other processes. Processes by default have nice value 0, so just make it bigger (say +10). You have to be root to give a process negative niceness.

Comment: Just as a note, reducing the CPU usage may also be a energy-consumption issue. Not sure if this is the case anyway.

Comment: Just doing recursive directory and file list, such as, if this is a directory, recurse, else add file name to array, repeat until done. Just doing this spikes energy consumption and high cpu load if there are many files and directories, like if you try this on your home directory

Comment: Just a thought - you're presumably appending to some sort of dynamic array or list - if an array, how are you growing it. (If you grow by a constant amount then you'll get an amortised number of copies that's quadratic in the list size.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Operation Queues](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW32) section of the in the *Concurrency Programming Guide* describes the process for changing the priority of a `NSOperation`:

> #### Changing the Underlying Thread Priority
>
> In OS X v10.6 and later, it is possible to configure the execution priority of an operation’s underlying thread. Thread policies in the system are themselves managed by the kernel, but in general higher-priority threads are given more opportunities to run than lower-priority threads. In an operation object, you specify the thread priority as a floating-point value in the range 0.0 to 1.0, with 0.0 being the lowest priority and 1.0 being the highest priority. If you do not specify an explicit thread priority, the operation runs with the default thread priority of 0.5.
>
> To set an operation’s thread priority, you must call the `setThreadPriority:` method of your operation object before adding it to a queue (or executing it manually). When it comes time to execute the operation, the default start method uses the value you specified to modify the priority of the current thread. This new priority remains in effect for the duration of your operation’s main method only. All other code (including your operation’s completion block) is run with the default thread priority. If you create a concurrent operation, and therefore override the start method, you must configure the thread priority yourself.

Having said that, I'm not sure how much of a performance difference you'll really see from adjusting the thread priority. For more dramatic performance changes, you may have to use timers, sleep/suspend the thread, etc.

If you're scanning the file system looking for changed files, you might want to refer to the the [File System Events Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for guidance of lightweight techniques for responding to file system changes.